# Updating more than one cell value in Primefaces DataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Using the [example from Primefaces DataTable Edit](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) I've changed the Year column to display Prices instead and added a footer which displays a calculated total price.

```
<f:facet name="footer">
    <h:outputText id="carstotal" value="Total: #{dtEditView.totalSales}" />
</f:facet>
```

**Is there a way to update also this total value when changing any of the price cells?** Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try to add an ajax event `keyup` ?!?

Comment: I've only used the onCellEdit() method from EditView.java where I've put the  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:cars2:carstotal"); in the if statement, but no success... carstotal is the id of the footer element.

Comment: I've also tried that example from possible duplicate but that is not complete. The refreshFooter(); is not defined in the example. And putting oncomplete="" to <p:ajax> makes DataTable to not render properly when clicking and modifying a cell... Anyway, there is a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After some workarounds a solution would be to have both bellow lines in **cars.xhtml** inside the `<h:form>` tag:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="onCellEdit" update=":form:msgs :form:cars2:carstotal" />
```

and

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onCellEdit}" oncomplete="onCellEdit()" />
```

The `h:outputText` updates its value on changing table cells but messages won't appear in top right corner now even if this is declared in the `update=":form:msgs :form:cars2:carstotal"`

Comment: I accidentally removed my comment, but it is better to mark the Q as a duplicate instead of a new answer. Since it is a 100% duplicate...